# How to count rows until some value with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

**I need to get counts of some rows with ORDER BY.**

how can I get count of the rows 
what are before orderId = 50
(I see answer is 3, but I need to have mysql query how to get it)

I have mysql query like this:

```
select c.id as customerId, o.id as orderId from orders o
inner join customers c on (c.id=o.customerId)
order by c.id asc, o.id desc
```

this query outputs:

```
customerId   orderId
19           36
19           35
19           34
31           50     
31           49
31           48
53           73
53           72
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to `COUNT` the number of results `WHERE` the `OrderId` is `< 50`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve? You're trying to count the rows in a descending order until you reach a row with a certain value? How can you be sure that there will always be a row with that *exact* value, and only one such row? Surely you'd want to check if *any* `orderId` value is less than 50? This sounds like a potential [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)...

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0 you may be able to do this with window functions, but I'm not very familiar with them yet.

Comment: Do you have to do it in SQL? This is trivial in a regular programming language.

Comment: @Valuator no, I don't want  WHERE OrderId is < 50, because customer with id 19 can have orderId bigger than 50 too.

Comment: Use a session variable to increment a row number for each row. Then get `MIN(row_number) WHERE orderId = 50`

Comment: If you can use a window function you can use the built-in `ROW_NUMBER()` function instead of a session variable.

Comment: Rows in a table aren't an order dataset. Unless you provide some field for order you can't say there are 3 rows before the 50. ( if that is what you want)

Comment: what is your sql version?

Comment: thank you @Barmar ROW_NUMBER() function works, but I just have to figure out now how to make that query with MIN(row_number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d44e453a5a1917ae0e4f3ee29430eb8f)**

```
SELECT Max(rn)
FROM (
    select customerId, 
           orderId , 
           @row := if( orderid = 50, 
                        null,
                        @row + 1 ) as rn
    from orders o
    cross join ( SELECT @row := 0 ) as vars
    order by customerId asc, orderId  desc
)  t
```

if can use row_number

```
SELECT MIN(rn) - 1 as cnt
FROM (
    select customerId, 
           orderId , 
           row_number() over (order by customerId asc, orderId  desc ) as rn
    from orders
) t
WHERE orderId = 50;
```

Comment: your example with row_number working perfectly yes! I don't know how to thank you :)

Comment: I just needed to join customers table too, so final code: 


SELECT MIN(rn) - 1 as cnt
FROM (
    select c.id as customerId, 
           o.id as orderId, 
           row_number() over (order by c.id asc, o.id desc ) as rn
    from orders o
    inner join customers c on (c.id=o.customerId) 
) t
WHERE orderId = 50;